# Understanding schematic diagram and transition matrices

Tags: probability, probability-theory, information-theory

I am reading Yeung's Information theory and network coding. In Examples 3.12, 3.13, and 3.14, the author uses schematic diagrams for the random variables. This is Example 3.13:
[image: Example 3.13]

This is definition of $Z$:

[image: Define Z]

In Example 3.13, how do I understand this schematic diagram? What are these switches, these boxes?
$p_{1}(y|x),p_{2}(y|x)$ are transition matrices. What are transition matrices? Or can you recommand places where I can learn about these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty standard in info theory. Basically the transition matrix enumerates the conditional distributions for the channel. Let
$X \in {\cal X}=\{x_1,\ldots,x_k\},$ and $Y \in {\cal Y}=\{y_1,\ldots,y_n\},$ then
$$
M=\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
p(y_1|x_1)& \ldots & p(y_n|x_1) \\
p(y_1|x_2)& \ldots & p(y_n|x_2) \\
\vdots & \ldots & \vdots \\
p(y_1|x_1)& \ldots & p(y_n|x_k) \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
is the transition matrix.

As for the diagram, based on the value of a random variable $Z$ which equals 1 with probability $\lambda$ and equals 2 with probability $\overline{\lambda}=1-\lambda,$ the conditional distribution is equal to $M_1=[p_1(y_j|x_i)]$ or $M_2=[p_2(y_j|x_i)],$ respectively.

Comment: why are there two transition matrices? What are $p_1,p_2$ here?

Comment: $p_1$ and $p_2$ are the two different transition matrices which are chosen by $Z$

Comment: Are $p_1,p_2$ the same transition matrix? From your definition of transition matrix, the transition matrix is unique.

Comment: Sure it needs to be subscripted, I wrote a generic matrix and then told you there are two of them for the case above. But I cannot understand why this is so confusing for you, sorry.

Comment: Is $p_1$ related to $X$, $p_2$ related to $Y$? The question itself only has $p$. So I don't know where $p_1,p_2$ come from. I will skip this part. This is the first time I am learning information theory, and I don't have a good background in probability theory. Thanks for your help!